# Same Bookmark for Multiple Locations MS-Word

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vba

I am feeding Excel data into a Word document with Excel VBA. When doing this, I have many bookmarks in Word. Sometimes I need to pull the same value from Excel and feed it to multiple bookmarks in the Word doc. Can I use one bookmark instead of multiple ones?

```
Dim totalCount As String
wdApp.Selection.GoTo what:=-1, Name:="Total_tickets"
totalCount = Format(shSLA.Range("E4").End(xlDown).Value)
wdApp.Selection.TypeText totalCount


Dim totalResponded As String
wdApp.Selection.GoTo what:=-1, Name:="Closed_tickets"
totalResponded = Format(shSLA.Range("M4").End(xlDown).Value)
wdApp.Selection.TypeText totalResponded


Dim totalOpen As String
wdApp.Selection.GoTo what:=-1, Name:="Pending_tickets"
totalOpen = Format(shSLA.Range("R4").End(xlDown).Value)
wdApp.Selection.TypeText totalOpen


''Reusing the same variables for different bookmarks now.
wdApp.Selection.GoTo what:=-1, Name:="Service_Request_Summary_TotaA"
wdApp.Selection.TypeText totalCount

wdApp.Selection.GoTo what:=-1, Name:="Service_Request_Summary_TotaB"
wdApp.Selection.TypeText totalCount


wdApp.Selection.GoTo what:=-1, Name:="Service_Request_Summary_Resolved"
wdApp.Selection.TypeText totalResponded


wdApp.Selection.GoTo what:=-1, Name:="Service_Request_Summary_Pending"
wdApp.Selection.TypeText totalOpen
```

Comment: What's the code you're using?

Comment: No responses? Not doable at all?

Comment: I don't understand. You run excel VBA, get a value and then insert it into word at specific bookmarks? And what do you want to change?

Comment: I am using VBA to populate some fields (marked by bookmarks) in a Word doc and the data are coming from a spreadsheet. Some data are entered into the doc multiple times at different bookmarks. Can I use one bookmark for those locations?

Comment: I read that as "I want the same bookmark at different places in word" - which no, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's cumbersome to have multiple bookmarks. I want to know if there is a way around it.

Comment: "Can I use one bookmark for those locations?" - basic purpose of a bookmark is to mark a text and reach it from other locations through a link, you can't have a link pointing to multiple locations. You probably need to use [custom document property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195603.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead of bookmark. You can insert the same property in multiple locations of a document and update them just at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Word doc, you could create one bookmark and then cross-reference the bookmark text.

So you would create/set the bookmark for a particular value in one place and then (instead of creating multiple other bookmarks for the same value) at each other place you want the same value to appear, insert cross-references.  In the Cross-reference dialog, just change the Reference type (top left dropdown) to Bookmark and Insert reference to (top right dropdown) to Bookmark text.

Then when you update all fields in your document (ctrl A then F9) the cross-references will update to the same value as your one bookmark.